# GETS request not works after deploy

Tags: deployment, web-deployment

Works with the digital ocean server, mongo atlas and nodejs , front react

This is the problem I get in all the get requests on the site.
[image: This is the problem I get in all the get requests on the site.]

When I check like this I do get the information from mongo atlas

[image]

And that's what I get from cmd

[image]

[[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a few things going on

1. The first screen shot says data.error is not defined.. So there is no .error as part of the data object, you may want to place that in a try catch OR if the call is promis based

   ```
   then .catch( (e) =>{
   console.log(e)
   })
   ```
2. The later part of you post shows the error shows both apps are running on port 3000. PM2 in cluster mode will take care of multiple apps / port issues but if you are using PM2 to manage multiple applications they will need to be on different ports and then via nginx proxy 80 to that location.

Comment: Thanks for treatment,
The problem was solved, I just restarted the computer and everything works fine probably something was running that prevented it from updating